# is there an event that fires at a specific time?

Tags: .net, events, timer, scheduler

Is there a .NET event that fires at a specific time (eg. at 19:00) as opposed to timer which fires when the countdown finishes? It can be used as a scheduler to call certain method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529019/how-to-use-the-net-timer-class-to-trigger-an-event-at-a-specific-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

It's a great scheduling library for .net.

Comment: Yeah, I have quartz running in a windows service. Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly but you can use timer and check if it is 19:00 already it its elapsed event and then fire the required code.

Otherwise you can put your code in Task Scheduler to get it executed at 19:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to run a method at specified time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scheduler you can use a 3rd party library called [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)