# Timer to exact time by seconds

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, infinite-loop, .net-core, timespan

I'm trying to run an infinite loop in parallel with the other code, that is executed once a specific time acheived by SECOND.
In the below code I'm trying to touch the exact midnight  time, that is: 00 hh: 00 mm: 00 sec

```
using System;  // for Date/Time
using System.Threading.Tasks;  // for Parallel

public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
Parallel.Invoke(
() =>
     {
           Console.WriteLine("Begin first task...");
      },  // close first Action

async () =>
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
         var midNight = "00:00:00";
         while (true)
            {
              TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(midNight).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
              Console.WriteLine("looping at: {0:00} Days, {1:00} Hours, {2:00} Minutes, {3:00} Seconds, {4:00} Milliseconds", 
              duration.Days, duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds, duration.Milliseconds);

              if(duration.Days >= 1)
                await Task.Delay(8640000);
                    else if(duration.Hours >= 1)
                           await Task.Delay(360000);
                               else if(duration.Minutes >= 1)
                                      await Task.Delay(60000);
                                         else 
                                            await Task.Delay(1000);

              if(duration == TimeSpan.Zero) { 
                  Console.WriteLine("It is time... midnight is {0}", DateTime.Now);
    }  // close second Action `the async task`
)  // end of Parallel.Invoke
}  // End of Main
}  // End of Program
```

I was able to the `await` statement work correctly to reach the required point, but the lock the condition `if(duration == TimeSpan.Zero)` never become `true`
[image]

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, if there's less than a minute left, you still delay for a second (`await Task.Delay(1000);`)? Even if it's down to half a second? That could be your problem.

Comment: Could it be helpful if you used a Scheduled Task for that? Quartz.NET is a lib that may help you... See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529019/how-to-use-the-net-timer-class-to-trigger-an-event-at-a-specific-time

Comment: It's worth noting that what you're trying to do may not be possible unless you can be completely certain the loop will run several times per millisecond, which external factors (e.g. garbage collection) could interfere with. You may be better having a flag for the time having been reached or passed.

Comment: Unrelated but potentially nasty bug here: you're using an `async` lambda as an argument to `Parllel.Invoke`, which offers no async support. The second argument (`Func<Task>`) will only block until you hit the `await` statement. If your first `Action` happens to finish by then, `Parallel.Invoke` will complete and the program will terminate immediately without waiting for the `Task` created by the `async` delegate to complete.

Comment: There is no such thing as an exact time. This is a consequence of the quantum nature of the universe. What are you actually trying to do? How close do you actually need to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your program can't work as you showed because your `TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(midNight).Subtract(DateTime.Now);` never will be positive. Second you main function will return almost immediately. Anyway you can try my solution for your problem:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () =>{Console.WriteLine("Begin first task...");},
            async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
                DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
                while (true)
                {
                    TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("looping at: {0:00} Days, {1:00} Hours, {2:00} Minutes, {3:00} Seconds, {4:00} Milliseconds", 
                                      duration.Days, duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds, duration.Milliseconds);

                    int delay = (int)(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1.0).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds/2);
                    await Task.Delay(delay>0?delay:0);

                    if(duration.Days >= 1) 
                    { 

                        Console.WriteLine("It is time... midnight is {0}", DateTime.Now);

                        startDate = DateTime.Today;
                    }

                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This will not provide you super precision as on normal PC you can't get it (you could use IRQ to get better accuracy but solution like that is far more complex).

Also as prof of concept [link to 10s version](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_csharp_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTl81Slg5bGI0MWs).

**At time version:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
                TimeSpan eventTime = new TimeSpan(0,18,16,53,123); //set when run event (ex. 18:16:53.123)
                DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.Add(eventTime);
                if(endDate<DateTime.Now) endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);
                while (true)
                {
                    TimeSpan duration = endDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                    Console.WriteLine("looping at: {0:00} Days, {1:00} Hours, {2:00} Minutes, {3:00} Seconds, {4:00} Milliseconds", duration.Days, duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds, duration.Milliseconds);

                    if(duration.TotalMilliseconds <= 0.0)
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("It is time... {0}", DateTime.Now);

                        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);
                        continue;
                    }

                    int delay = (int)(duration.TotalMilliseconds/2);
                    await Task.Delay(delay>0?delay:0);

                }
            }
        );
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to compare it with a given time, other than the midnight?

Comment: @HasanAYousef I have got little bug (I mixed 10s version with midnight version) but it's ok now. Now to your question. You will need to calculate endDate not startDate. And then after duration cross 0 you will need to recalculate it again and do your stuff. I will post example in a minute. But for the future pleas post your requirements with your question and not add them later as they can completely change implementation.

Comment: @HasanAYousef I added new version.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is perfect now, I can achieve accuracy per millisecond :) will consider your note for future posts, appreciated.

Comment: @HasanAYousef you’re welcome. Accuracy will heavily dependent on environment you are running your app for ex. if you do it in background and a user is playing video game it could be even a couple of seconds before your app execute your event. Please also up vote if you are satisfy with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by changing the condition from:

```
if(duration == TimeSpan.Zero)
```

to:

```
if(duration.Days == 0 && duration.Hours == 0 && duration.Minutes == 0 && duration.Seconds == 0)
```

and to avoid the double occurrence of the event, i added another `await` level, so the new one became like:

```
if(duration.Days >= 1)
   await Task.Delay(8640000);
      else if(duration.Hours >= 1)
         await Task.Delay(360000);
            else if(duration.Minutes >= 1)
                await Task.Delay(60000);
                   else if(duration.Seconds >= 1)
                      await Task.Delay(1000);
                          else
                              await Task.Delay(500);
```

I tried adding the `if(duration.Milliseconds >= 1) await(1)` but did not work, my output became as shown below:
[image]

Comment: You might want to do `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));`, `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));` and so on down the chain to make it easier to read.

Comment: From technical point of view your approach is wrong as your application  will end up not saying "it's time" if freeze for 2s at midnight.

Comment: @Logman, it looks it really freeze, but why this happened, still did not get it.

Comment: @HasanAYousef as you probably working with normal computers and not RTC systems you can't depend on exact moment in time. There may be multiple reason why your application is not working but whole idea of checking if now is midnight is wrong. One of solution is to check if you cross midnight and after that do something and reset timer. Also `Task.Delay` don't guarantee it will wait exactly N milliseconds only that it will wait at least N milliseconds.

Comment: #Logman can you please post a proposed solution so I test it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your case, the `duration` is never zero, it goes from plus some milliseconds to minus some milliseconds.

What I would do: If `duration` is less than one second, wait for `duration` and then just assume it's the right time. In code:

```
if (duration.Days >= 1)
    await Task.Delay(8640000);
else if (duration.Hours >= 1)
    await Task.Delay(360000);
else if (duration.Minutes >= 1)
    await Task.Delay(60000);
else if (duration.Seconds >= 1)
    await Task.Delay(1000);
else
{
    // defensive check in case duration is already negative
    // this should not normally happen, but is still possible
    if (duration > TimeSpan.Zero)
        await Task.Delay(duration);
    Console.WriteLine("It is time... midnight is {0}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

This won't give you millisecond accuracy, but it should be the right second, under normal circumstances.

Comment: your approach looks to be very logic, I'll check it by Sunday and confirm you by Monday. Thanks