# Give advice on how to create a system of daily tasks for the discord bot

Tags: c#, discord.net

I apologize in advance that the question is not on the topic but I need help. I am learning to write my own code and I have a task to make a system of daily rewards and that each user has a quantitative balance. I need to build an action plan to successfully make this command, the only thing I know about this command is to work with the database. You can build me an action plan so that I can successfully create this team and it works.

Comment: This question is far too broad for stackoverflow. Try to find a tutorial and give something a try, then come back if you get stuck on something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first piece you will need is some sort of scheduler. This will need to run in a thread, because Discord.Net expects you to do all side processing in secondary threads. This will also need to keep track of when the last time it was run, in case your bot happened to not be up RIGHT at 7:00:00.0000 (or whenever you schedule your daily tasks to run) to make sure they run anyway.

This will cover the first part:
[How to use the .NET Timer class to trigger an event at a specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529019/how-to-use-the-net-timer-class-to-trigger-an-event-at-a-specific-time)

The second part involves writing some "did I run yet?" sort of flag, probably checking against your database or some small status file.

The next piece is a list of tasks to run. This is a very open-ended section and is probably as simple as just writing a method for each thing that needs to be done daily. 
 It's a good principle to keep each task in a separate method for ease of code maintenance. You can then attach all your tasks to a multicast delegate and have it run them all as a batch.

This part is fairly easy, actually. A normal eventhandler wrapper with...

...An event args container:

```
public class RepeatedTaskEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  //Any event arguments you need to pass in here.
}
```

...An event

```
public EventHandler<RepeatedTaskEventArgs> RunDailies;
```

...Something to call to trigger the event.

```
public static void PerformDailyEvents()
{
  RepeatedTaskEventArgs dailyTaskArgs = new RepeatedTaskEventArgs();
  RunDailies?.Invoke(DateTime.Now, dailyTaskArgs);
}
```

...Something to actually run.

```
private void SomeDailyAction(object sender, RepeatedTaskEventArgs e)
{
  //Your daily code goes here.
}
```

Then, in your program startup:

```
private Program()
{
  //Just some example lines from my bot. Yours will be different:
  Client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig() { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info });
  Client.Connected += Connected;
  Client.MessageRecieved += Client_MessageReceived;

  //Then do your daily event setup:
  Execute(() => RunDailyEvents(), new DateTime(2020, 5, 8, 7, 0, 0));

  //Register an action.
  RunDailies += SomeDailyAction;
  //You can do multiple actions, since delegates are fine with that.
  RunDailies += SomeOtherDailyAction;
}

//This is one of the answers from the other Stack Overflow article. Use whichever approach works best for you. I chose this one because it's short and this is an example.
public void Execute(Action action, DateTime ExecutionTime)
{
    Task WaitTask = Task.Delay((int)ExecutionTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
    WaitTask.ContinueWith(_ => action);
    WaitTask.Start();
}
```

My code isn't 100% of the functionality you need, but hopefully it should give you a general idea of what it should look like.