# NET core worker service check if time equals 8 pm and call a console app exe

Tags: c#, .net-core

Hi I need to call a console app exe file from a worker service.
I have four different exe's that needs to be called at 8pm ,9pm, 12 and 1am respectively.

So i want to check if datetime now hours and minute value == 08:00 pm then call the AMload.exe
if date time is 09:00 pm then call pkLoad.exe

I have this code currently which checks for time ranges but looking for a check that can just do equals check for specific time. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
using (var aMprocess = new Process())
        {
        TimeSpan Time11PMStart = new TimeSpan(AMStartHr, AMStartMin, 0);
        TimeSpan Time11PMEnd = new TimeSpan(AMEndHr, AMEndMin, 0);
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

            if ((now > start) && (now < end))
            {

                WriteLog("Log", String.Format("{0} @ {1}", "Calling the amJob at - " + DateTime.Now, "from the " + " runAMLoad() Method "));

                amProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                amProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\AMLoadCore.exe";
}
```

Comment: Look at this question, maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529019/how-to-use-the-net-timer-class-to-trigger-an-event-at-a-specific-time

Comment: "from a worker service" we're going to need more context here. Is this an `IHostedService` in an asp-net core web process in IIS? A generic host console app running as a windows service? Is there a particular reason you aren't just using an OS scheduled task?

Comment: Oof, don't bother. Just use the Windows Task Scheduler or a cron job, depending on your target OS

Comment: @Caius We currently have windows task scheduler and its randomly not calling the exes as scheuduled, so we are trying to move away from task scheduler and come up with .net background service.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like troubleshooting that problem will be simpler than writing your own service..