# To raise an event every hour has passed in system clock

Tags: c#

I want to raise an event every time each hour has passed in system clock.
For example, I run my program at 7:45 am then the event should be raised at 8:00 am, not at 8:45 am.
After the event raised at 8:00 am, then this event should be raised at every hour 9:00 am, 10:00 am, 11:00 am, etc...

Can anyone help me to show some code...
I use C#.net...
Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE:**

Now I get the simple solution for my question. Therefore I would like to share this solution. lboshuizen's answer is already correct. My answer is same logic with lboshuizen's answer but more detail and exact.

Firstly it needs to use Timer. Timer basically works based on milliseconds which sometimes needs additional calculation. Therefore, I would like to implement milliseconds to minute formatting function as first.

```
int CalculateMillisecondUntilNextHour()
{
     int REMAIN_MINUTE = 60 - DateTime.Now.Minute;
     DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
     DateTime nexthour = now.AddMinutes((minute)).AddSeconds(now.Second * -1).AddMilliseconds(now.Millisecond * -1);

     TimeSpan interval = nexthour - now;
     return (int)interval.TotalMilliseconds;
}

void CheckEachHourPassed()
{
     System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     t.Interval = CalculateMillisecondUntilNextHour();
     t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
     t.Enabled = true;
}

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Raise Your Event");
     t.Interval = CalculateTimerInterval(REMAIN_MINUTE);
}
```

At here, the main working function is CheckEachHourPassed(). Call this function where you want to start your event scheduler.

Comment: google will tell you for sure

Comment: @daveL, Nothing, that's obvious

Comment: what have you tried? Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122509/is-there-an-event-that-fires-at-a-specific-time)?

Comment: If you need something to run every hour, use a scheduler (e.g. the one built into windows) rather than implementing a scheduler yourself inside your own code. Especially if you're not going to be doing anything for the remaining 59 minutes of each hour.

Comment: @lblshuizen, I already tried threading, stopwatch, and timer. I only tried to request yours suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code (*implementation is left as an excercise to the reader*)

```
var currentTime = Time.Now()
var deltaMinutes  = Calculate_minutes_till_next_full_hour(currentTime);
wait(deltaMinutes);
var timer = new timer();
timer.Every().Minutes(60).Execute(() => Code());
```

Comment: sir, I really appreciate for your answer. But I think if you know the exact answer, you should give the answer instead of giving the exercise. What the matters, your pseudo code could give me ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` by fixing `Interval` property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the

```
timer.Every().Minutes(60).Execute(() => Code());
```

over time may actually get out of sync with the real time.

How about running this in a thread

```
var lastMoment = DateTime.Now;
while(true)
   if(DateTime.Now.Hour != lastMoment.Hour)
   {
       //Raise ElaspedHourEvent
       //Thread.Sleep(1000);
   ]
```

it might not fire the event until at most a second after the hour but at least it won't get out of sync.